# MRU list in Visual studio is missing

Tags: visual-studio

A couple of months ago, the MRU list in Visual Studio stopped working. Neither the File menu or the start page shows any recently opened projects or solutions. I honestly  have no clue what I did to cause this, but perhaps someone who knows more about the murky depths of VS might be able to hazard a guess at what caused it to disappear, and even better, how to get it back?

It is a pretty normal VS2k8 Team System installation with SP1, running on a 32-bit XP SP3 machine.

Edit:
The registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectMRUList exists, but is empty.
Permissions for that registry key seem pretty normal. The user I'm running VS as has both read and write access to it (and has admin privileges in general).

Answer (score 2):

You might run RegMon / FileMon (ProcessMon) from SysInternals as to ensure it is access the correct path, and that there are not permissions problems, etc

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if you've already checked the obvious:  there's a setting under Tools, Options, Environment, General, where you can set the # of items to be displayed in MRU lists.  Is it possible that somehow this has gotten set to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Try out Recently Used Files (supported for 2010,2012 and 2013) that maintains an MRU list on a per-project basis.

Visual Studio 2012, 2013: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a61cbd1d-b5a2-490b-a6bb-f0ea3ecf214a
Visual Studio 2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45283881-5a62-4dc1-8ffb-4cbc02709947

Its free, and very efficiently manages the MRU lists for your projects.